# problems with mysql connection

Tags: java, html, mysql

hi I'm developing a small web page that consists of connecting with mysql but I am running the following error how do I solve it ??? thank you

is try this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>
> Tue Mar 05 22:18:36 CET 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
>
> SQL exception:Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

```
public static void loadDbProperties(String dbLogin, String dbPassword) throws IOException {
        String dbIp = "localhost";
        String dbPort = "3306";

        DBConnectionPool.dbProperties = new Properties();

        DBConnectionPool.dbProperties.put("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); 
        DBConnectionPool.dbProperties.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://"+ dbIp+":"+ dbPort +"?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=CET");

        DBConnectionPool.dbProperties.put("username", dbLogin);
        DBConnectionPool.dbProperties.put("password", dbPassword);          
    }   
}
```

Comment: So, have you tried setting useSSL=false, or setting useSSL=true and providing a truststore for server certificate verification like the error message asks you to?  If so, please [edit] your question to include that information, along with what problem you are having with it.

Comment: May be use this approach to connect https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database